# Ruby on Rails check box not updating on form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, view

I have an entries controller that allows users to add contact information the website. The user-submitted information isn't visible to users until the administrator checks a check box and submits the form. So basically my problem is that if I check the check box as an administrator while initially creating an entry (entries#new) the entry will be publicly visible as expected, but if a non-admin user creates an entry (the normal user view doesn't include the 'live' check box, only the admin one does) then that entry is stuck in limbo because the entries#edit view for some reason doesn't update the boolean check box value when logged in as an admin.

entries#new view:

```
<% form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  Name<br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  Mailing Address<br />
  <%= f.text_field :address %>

  #...
  <%- if current_user -%>
    <%= f.label :live %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :live %>
  <%- end -%>
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

entries#edit (only accessible by admin) view:

```
<% form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  Mailing Address<br />
  <%= f.text_field :address %>

  <%= f.label :live %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :live %>

  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>

<% end %>
```

EDIT:

entries_controller.rb update method:

```
def update
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])
      flash[:notice] = 'Entry was updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@entry) }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

entry.rb:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_mappable
  acts_as_taggable_on   :tags
  validates_presence_of :name, :tag_list
  validates_length_of   :name, :maximum => 64
  validates_length_of   :tag_list, :maximum => 128, :allow_blank => false
  validates_length_of   :paddress, :maximum => 128, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :address, :maximum => 128, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :tollfreephone, :in => 7..32, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :phone, :in => 7..32, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :phone2, :in => 7..32, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :mobile, :in => 7..32, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :fax, :in => 7..32, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :email, :in => 7..48, :allow_blank => true
  validates_format_of   :email,
                    :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i,
                    :on => :create, :allow_blank => true

  validates_length_of   :website, :maximum => 64, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of   :description, :maximum => 1024, :allow_blank => true
  attr_accessible       :name, :tag_list, :paddress, :address, :tollfreephone,
                        :phone, :phone2, :mobile, :fax, :email, :website,
                        :description 
  validate              :required_info
  before_save           :geocode_paddress
  searchable_on         :name, :address, :phone, :phone2, :mobile, :fax, :email,
                    :website, :category, :description
private
  def required_info
    if( phone.empty?  and phone2.empty? and tollfreephone.empty? and 
        mobile.empty? and fax.empty?    and email.empty?         and 
        website.empty? 
      ) 
      errors.add_to_base "Please have at least one form of contact information."
    end
  end
  def geocode_paddress
    # if paddress is nil or empty set the old values to nil and return    
    ((self.lat = self.lng = nil); return true) if paddress.empty?
    g=Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(paddress)
    (errors.add(:paddress,"Could not Geocode address");
       return false) unless g.success
    self.lat, self.lng = g.lat, g.lng
  end
end
```

Any ideas as to why an administrator can't update the :live check box from the edit view?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. I'm new to rails. I can post more code if it's needed. Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: please post your entries_controller.rb update method & entry.rb  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having an [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002281) call

```
attr_accessible       :name, :tag_list, :paddress, :address, :tollfreephone,
                    :phone, :phone2, :mobile, :fax, :email, :website,
                    :description
```

Which is great as it'll avoid users to update other fields than the ones you allow them to.
But your `live` field isn't in there.

So it's value is filtered by rails as the user isn't allow to update that field. Add it to the fields in the attr_accessible call and you'll be able to edit it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely missed that.

Comment: I would recommend not adding it, that attribute should not be accessible, because then users could set it themselves. It would defeat the whole purpose of attr_accessible. Instead, do `@entry.live = params[:entry][:live]` before the call to update_attributes.